# Hide the elements of li when clicking on different images by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have displayed some text in li and set a image above it(there are 2 images and it is shown one by one when clicked in it.)

I want to hide the text of li(whose class is "ans") when I click on one image and show the content when clicked in another image (which appears after clicking first image).

these are my codes:

```html
<div class="btn">
    <div class="showhide" id="showhide"><img id="showhideimg"></div></div>
<ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</li>
      <li class="ans">Hi there!</li>
      <li>Lorem, ipsum?</li>
      <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
```

I have made javascript to display image one after another when clicking on it but paused when it comes to disable the elements of li when I click on specific image:(.

```js
<script>
var img = 0;
var images = [ 'eye.png', 'eyeslash.png'];
var showHide = document.getElementById('showhide');
var showHideImg = document.getElementById('showhideimg');

showHide.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  setImage();
});

function setImage() {
  if (img > images.length - 1) {
    img = 0;
  }
  showHideImg.src = images[img++];
}

setImage();
</script>
```

Comment: where is the element with id `showhide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through by classname and then show and hide.

```js
var img = 0;
var images = [ 'https://i.imgur.com/KfehB6D.png', 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gzk.svg' ];
var showHide = document.getElementById('showhide');
var showHideImg = document.getElementById('showhideimg');

showHide.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  setImage();
  
});

function setImage() {
  if (img > images.length - 1) {
    img = 0;
  }

  var ans = document.getElementsByClassName("ans");
  for(var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++){
     ans[i].style.display = (img==0 ? "list-item": "none");
  }
  
  showHideImg.src = images[img++];
}

setImage();
```

```css
#showhideimg{
width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
    <div class="showhide" id="showhide"><img id="showhideimg"></div></div>
<ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?</li>
      <li class="ans">Hi there!</li>
      <li>Lorem, ipsum?</li>
      <li class="ans">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: wow wow wow, can you please please just reverse it, I mean i want to set text visible in dafault but it is not visible in default @Geetanjali

Comment: Yeah sure, check the updated code. If it answers your question, please mark it as accepted to help others.

Comment: instead of 'https://i.imgur.com/KfehB6D.png' i want to add "eye.svg" can you please help me @Geetanjali?

Comment: Yes you can simply replace the URL with your own path :)

Comment: it is not showing for svg but it is working for png, how can i make it work for svg? @Geetanjali?

Comment: I updated the code with one svg image and its working :)

Comment: please check by downloading it; it is not working for me :(

Comment: In your case the svg image path might be wrong. Please check it again and provide the correct path to your image.

Comment: no path is correct; please check it once in offline?

Comment: these are the link for both svg image; please download it, locate it and test; it isnot working :( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n-ZhpkveFivyVGmJ8P4gIBkytyfwbw9g and https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_pIBJG4-ytXuyQuzpQ3HsoxGFbbvY7WL @Geetanjali?